# Intel wireless 7260 won't connect to any wireless network in Ubuntu 15.10 on a Toshiba Chromebook 2

Tags: networking, drivers, chromebook

various people online said that it was worth voiding the warranty to get access to full Linux, and i would like to use kden live on my toshiba chromebook 2 FHD for basic editing, but i cannot connect to any wireless network, it can find the nearby networks but when i enter the password and press connect it keeps connecting before eventually disconnecting, btw this is my first time in linux properly, please help, i wan't a working laptop back!